# Search details for specific category

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, json, autocomplete

I have developed php ajax autocomplete search and there I created separate tabs for search data which belongs 5 categories. Currently 5 tabs autocomplete results shown data only for specific category, but when I enter a value other than the autocomplete results its gives all the results which belongs to all categories not for specifc category.

Please advise me how to fix this.

category 01 : below code im using for search data related to category id=82

```
        $searchp=$_GET["term"];
    $query = $db -> getQuery(true);

     $query="SELECT * FROM content where title like '%".$searchp."%'AND categories_id=82 order by title ASC ";
    $db -> setQuery($query);
    // Load the results as a list of associated arrays.
    $results = $db -> loadAssocList();
    $json=array();
    foreach ($results as $json_result) {
        $json[] = array('value' => $json_result["title"], 'label' => $json_result["title"]);
    }


    echo json_encode($json);


==============================

              jQuery.noConflict();
                 jQuery(function(){
                     jQuery("#searchp").autocomplete({
                         source:'personal.php',
                        delay: 300 ,
                         minLength:1
                     });

});
```

Comment: So you only want results from category 82, but it is showing results from all when there aren't any matches?  I'm trying to paraphrase what you said here.

Comment: P.S.  `'value' => $json_result["title"]` <- is this supposed to be title?

Comment: @Devon : yes , its showing all results from other categories if there anything similar.  Ex: if i search "books" if there no any resutls in category 82 but have in other categories its shows those. i want to not showing data which related to other categories. but drop down only load data which related to particular category

Comment: @Devon : yes its title... im searching data from title

Comment: Okay, I just noticed both value and label were the same thing.  I would suspect value should be an ID but that isn't the problem you are having anyways.  Is this your full personal.php?  The query you have seems to be locked to category 82.  It is categories_id and not category_id?

Comment: yes its full personal.php and cateogries_id is the column name of table .

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your query.  I'm not sure what SQL API/class you are using, but I'm assuming that is where the problem lies.  Output the query itself and test it independently. P.S. this query is subject to SQL injections since you aren't using a prepared query for the user input.